# Do you see any kind of problem with this C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    void DoSomething(int x){}   
};

void func(int i)
{
    A *pa = new A();
    pa->DoSomething(i);
    delete pa;
}
```

Do you guys see any problem with this code?
I can only see following two:

1. *func* is only operating on object of class A and should be made *member* of A.
2. object of class A should be created on the *stack* instead of heap.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I call shenanigans on both of those.

Comment: I only call shenanigans on number 1.

Comment: @Ignacio:  Why do you call shenanigans on (2)?

Comment: There is no reason to declare a destructor that does nothing (unless you are declaring it `virtual` so a class can be used as a public base class).  The only reason you would need to declare an empty default constructor is if you declare some other constructor that would suppress generation of the default constructor.

Comment: IMO, any time you spell out the destructor, you should probably spell it with `virtual`. And it's usually a good idea to do that as soon as you define the class. It's too easy to miss that little word if you don't put it in early. There are some cases where you may really want to avoid having virtual destructors, but they are the with-care exceptional cases.

Comment: @Steve314: I completely disagree. Adding `virtual` to a destructor says that things are likely to derive from this class. This means that users need to think carefully about any copying operations. This is the wrong signal if the class is designed to have value semantics. A `virtual` destructor is something you should make a conscious decision about adding, it shouldn't be an automatic action.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I am so on your side on this.

Comment: @Charles - Of course copying operations *always* need care in the presence of inheritance, and often even without inheritance (shallow vs. deep etc), but future extensions and inheritance happen. If a class should never be inherited from, I say so in a comment and wish for a `final` keyword. Relying on inferences seems a bit unreliable. I understand the it's-a-red-flag viewpoint, but it isn't really a red flag to me. Making assignment and the copy constructor private - now *that's* a red flag for copy semantics.

Comment: @Steve314: I'm not saying you shouldn't make the copy constructor and copy assignment operator private for classes that shouldn't be copied. I'm just saying that you shouldn't make a destructor virtual for non-polymorphic classes that can and should be copied. I'd go so far as saying that to do so is incorrect. As a class designed I haven't given any incentive to inherit from such a class but it doesn't matter to me if someone does. I may slice such a class if passed to me by reference but as there's no polymorphic behaviour I'm just using the base class "value" that I care about.

Comment: @Charles - it's off the original point, but... slicing that value is potentially dangerous. For example, the base classes private internals may include a member pointer - and in the object you're slicing, that member pointer may reference a field that doesn't exist in the base. Basically, just because derived inherits base, doesn't mean that the slice you'll get is valid when copied out. If it's just an aggregate of fields, fine, but that to me is a struct rather than a class and (normally) won't get a virtual destructor. IOW, maybe our difference is more about words than principle.

Comment: @Steve314: Don't forget that I've designed the base class to be copied. It seems unlikely that I'd have a arbitrarily assignable raw pointer in such base class and if someone has (for whatever reason) inherited from such a class and passed it in to be copied it's their responsibility to ensure that any externally referenced objects (including their inherited class instance) are maintained while needed. My argument applies to classes that hide data and have functionality so I'm not just talking about aggregate structures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> object of class `A` should be created on the stack instead of heap.

Yes, `pa` should be created as an automatic variable (on the stack) instead of dynamically (on the heap).

However, it's also wrong as written because it isn't exception-safe.  If `pa->DoSomething(i)` throws an exception, you will leak the object pointed to by `pa`.

The correct way to manage resource lifetimes is to use Scope-Bound Resource Management (SBRM; also called Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).  The RAII way to manage a dynamically allocated object is to use a smart pointer:

```
void func(int i)
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> pa(new A());
    pa->DoSomething(i);
}
```

Manual resource management is brittle and dangerous because it's easy to get wrong.  In this trivial example, it's easy to see that `pa->DoSomething(i)` does not throw an exception because it doesn't do anything at all.  But in almost every real program, it's not that easy.

Manual resource management quickly becomes very difficult as a program grows in size and complexity.  Automatic resource management using Scope-Bound Resource Management scales very well.

> `func` is only operating on object of class `A` and should be made member of `A`.

This is not correct.  You should only implement a function as a member function if it requires access to the internal state of the object.  This means that you should prefer to implement functions as non-member functions wherever possible.

The more member functions you have, the more work it takes to thoroughly test a class because there are more ways that the internal state of the class can be modified.

Herb Sutter explains this principle by breaking down the `std::string` class in his Guru of the Week article ["Monoliths Unstrung."](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)

Comment: Fair enough! and why func shouldn't be made member of A?

Comment: My rule is that if a method intuitively belongs to a class (it is an aspect of the abstraction that the class represents) then it's right for it to be a method, irrespective of anything else. Access to internal state? - well, the whole app may need (indirect) access to that state, and I'm quite happy to write methods that only access state by calling other methods of the same class.

Comment: @Steve314:  I'm a fan of [The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) wherein "both member and nonmember functions can be logically 'part of' a  class."

Comment: personally, if it's meant to be part of a class, I think it should be explicit that it's part of the class - but of course I recognise that principle too, and most classes have idioms that form part of the interface even though they're typically written on the outside. I think there's a difference between these things, though. A single function can trivially become a single method, and the implementation of that method is then precisely that - implementation, not interface. Larger patterns and idioms cannot be isolated so easily - they really are at the caller-callee interface.

Answer (score 2):

Any exception happens on func() while executing A::DoSomething() cause a memory leak. Use a smart pointer (e.g. std::auto_ptr)

Comment: DoSomething() 's body is empty, exception is very less likely!

Comment: @Rajendra Kumar Uppal: An exception is very much likely if `DoSomething()` actually does something! (e.g. if it calls `new` and fails with a `std::bad_alloc` exception.)

Answer (score 0):

Also, a class that needs a copy constructor, an assignment operator or a destructor typically needs all three (I know, this one is empty - just saying).

Comment: The rule is that if a class manages a resource, the big three should all be declared (the copy constructor, the copy assignment operator, and the destructor).  It isn't always the case that a class that has a user-declared constructor manages a resource; consider, for example, a base class with a public virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is this real code? Then the stateless class is completely superfluous, and `void DoSomething(int x)` should be a normal function. If not, post the *real* code, otherwise it's hard to give further advice.